# Mongodb pod consuming memory even though it is in idle state

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

When Inserting data in mongodb its memory usage increases then 
the data base is dropped and connections are closed, but still the memory usage continue to increase. 
I have already configured  wiredTiger to 700mb

As you can see the graph in the screen shot attached down,at every 30 mins data insertion and deletion takes place , which consumes max 10 minutes of time and then the connection breaks but as you can see in graph the memory usage continues to increase which then reaches its max limit and then the kuberntes pod starts showing trouble

[image: screenshot]